# Submitting a collection of checkboxes in MVC when the first checkbox is unchecked produces null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Basically I have a collection of strings, and I want to render them as checkboxes on the page. To do this, I have written this code:

```
@for (var i=0; i< Model.AvailableCats.Length; i++)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="Cats[@i]" value="@Model.Cats[i]" @(Model.Cats.Contains(Model.AvailableCats[i]) ? "checked=checked" : "") /> @Model.AvailableCats[i]
}
```

This produces checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bengal" name="Cats[0]">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Moggy" name="Cats[1]">
```

When submitted this works ok if both are checked, or if the first is checked, but if only the 2nd item is checked, it's only submitting Cats[1] and MVC does not map this into an array.

I'm sure the answer is very simple but how can I submit my collection of checkbox values?

Answer (score 1):

This is why `Html.Checkbox` actually adds a hidden input element *in addition* to the checkbox input. Checkboxes only submit a value if they are checked, so adding a hidden input with the same name, means that if it's not checked, *something* will be submitted, even if it's only an empty string.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bengal" name="Cats[0]">
<input type="hidden" name="Cats[0]" value="">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Moggy" name="Cats[1]">
<input type="hidden" name="Cats[1]" value="">
```

Comment: That is very clever, I thought you'd have to use javascript trickery but that is very elegant. Fortunately in my case it doesn't matter if the value is not submitted but that would work in many situations where it is important.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the answer was simple, just have the same name property on each one. It doesn't have to be unique and MVC binds it into a collection if more than one are submitted.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Bengal" name="Cats">
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="Moggy" name="Cats">
```

Surprised it took me that long.